# Does Lambda allow libstdc++.so.6? Does AWS lambda have GCC-8.0.1?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, gcc, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a question regarding files that are allowed to run on AWS Cloud.

I have a project that incorporates c++ files but uses python-wrappers. Therefore the project has .py and .cpp files.

Now, the issue comes down to when I try to deploy this project onto the cloud. I'm able to do it but I get a GLIBSTD error due to dependencies: (Unable to import module 'handler': /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /var/task/lgraph.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

This project is built on my ArchLinux machine, and I checked what dependencies are an issue, it is the libstdc++.so.6, as listed below.

**server1:~$/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++**

```
libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
libstdc++.so.5 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.5
libstdc++.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so
libstdc++.so (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so
```

**TL:DR: So does AWS Lambda not have gcc-8.0.1? Is it not able to understand how to compile this?**

The reason i'm asking about gcc-8.0.1. is because I went on docker and deployed this project, I got same GLIB error, so I manually installed gcc-8.0.1. on the docker container, and the program worked 100% perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but if you have the libstdc++.so.6 file, you can include in a lambda layer and deploy.

The .so file must be placed into the `lib/` folder before zipping, and upload the zip as a lambda layer. Then tie the layer to the function and it should work.

TL;DR

Lambda layers are simply zip files that get unzipped into the `opt/` directory of the lambda functions. The `opt/` directory is special because `opt/bin` is in the $PATH and `opt/lib` is in $LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

So if you place the pre-built library files like libstdc++.so.6 into the `lib/` folder of your lambda layer, you can then reference it from your running lambda function. You might also have to place the binary in the `bin/` folder to ensure everything works. But beware, currently the $PATH in lambda prioritizes other directories ahead of the `opt/bin` folder, so if the binary already exists in the lambda it will use the default version instead of the version in your layer. You'll need to modify the $PATH to ensure **YOUR** binary in the `/opt/bin` from your layer is used.